# why the coroutine exception handler double the original exception?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine

I implements my own `async`, I can't process the exception in a right way. why?

```
val expected = IllegalStateException();
val it = async<Any> {
    throw expected;
};

assert.that({ it.get() }, throws(equalTo(expected)));
//              ^--- but it throws a IllegalStateException(cause = expected)
```

### Source Code

```
interface Response<in T> {
    suspend fun yield(value: T);
}

interface Request<out T> {
    fun get(): T;
    fun <R> then(mapping: (T) -> R): Request<R>;
}

private val executor: ExecutorService = ForkJoinPool(20);
fun <T> async(block: suspend Response<T>.() -> Unit): Request<T> {
    return object : Request<T>, Response<T> {
        @Volatile var value: T? = null;

        var request: Continuation<Unit>? = block.createCoroutine(this, delegate {}).let {
            var task: Future<*>? = executor.submit { it.resume(Unit); };
            return@let delegate {
                try {
                    val current = task!!;
                    task = null;
                    current.get();
                } catch(e: ExecutionException) {
                    throw e.cause ?: e;
                }
            };
        };

        override fun <R> then(mapping: (T) -> R): Request<R> = async<R> {
            yield(mapping(get()));
        };

        override fun get(): T {
            return value ?: wait();
        }

        private fun wait(): T {
            val it = request!!;
            request = null;
            it.resume(Unit);
            return value!!;
        }

        suspend override fun yield(value: T) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    };
}

inline fun <T> delegate(noinline exceptional: (Throwable) -> Unit = { throw it; }, crossinline resume: (T) -> Unit): Continuation<T> {
    return object : Continuation<T> {
        override val context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext;


        override fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable) {
            exceptional(exception);
        }

        override fun resume(value: T) {
            resume(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the strange behavior is comes from java. the `ForkJoinTask#getThrowableException` will rethrow exception for the given task:

> Returns a **rethrowable** exception for the given task, if
>     available. To provide **accurate** stack traces, if the exception
>     was not thrown by the current thread, we try to **create a new
>     exception** of the same type as the one thrown, but with the
>     recorded exception as its cause. If there is no such
>     constructor, we instead try to use a **no-arg constructor**,
>     followed by `initCause`, to the same effect. If none of these
>     apply, or any fail due to other exceptions, we return the
>     recorded exception, which is still correct, although it may
>     contain a misleading stack trace.

which implies that if you don't want to rethrow exception for the give task you can make the exception constructor non-publicly, for example:

```
val exception = object: IllegalStateException(){/**/};
//                      ^--- its constructor only available in its scope
```